# Extracting multiple strings, according to a pattern, in a bash script

Tags: shell, awk, sed, string, replace

I'm writing a shell script to generate a directory listing.

as an input a receive a long html string :

```
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_china-seoul-startup-activity-6571925510337728512-acAw","$type":"com.traver.voyager.feed.actions.Action"},
link to post","url":"https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_reuters-top-news-on-twitter-activity-6571392661482233856-T3dO","$type":
article","$type":"com.traver.voyager.feed.actions.Action"},{"actionType":"SHARE_VIA","text":"Copy link to post","url":"https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_are-you-thinking-to-the-benefits-of-digitalization-activity-6570119712154451968-927T","$type":"com.traver.voyager
```

To make the output easily customizable, the script just display a url-table :

```
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_china-seoul-startup-activity-6571925510337728512-acAw
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_reuters-top-news-on-twitter-activity-6571392661482233856-T3dO
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_are-you-thinking-to-the-benefits-of-digitalization-activity-6570119712154451968-927T
```

the pattern to search is :
begins by "https://www." then XXXXX letters (dynamic size) then finishes with " (quote not to extract)

My current solution was based on cut -f but the total input size is dynamic, so it is not possible to find the pattern.

Comment: Is your long string html or json?  if json, use `jq` or a json-parsing library for the language of your choice.   If it's HTML, you can extract links from it easily with `lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "$URL"` (lynx can also read from a file or from stdin).

Comment: it is html with hexa and octal code I convert with recode tool. I tried your command but just it's ongoing and nothing happens.
what is $URL value ?

Comment: like this : lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "https://www" -stdin test07-09-B.txt  or lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "$URL" -stdin test07-09-B.txt

Comment: my "command" was not meant for you to type exactly. It was an example, showing the lynx options which can be used to extract URLs from HTML data.  "$URL" in the example is a stand-in for the original url you used to fetch the HTML data.  Or, as i mentioned, lynx can read a file or stdin.

Comment: btw, your sample "html string" **really** doesn't look like HTML.  It looks like json or some very similar structured text.   if it's not actually HTML, lynx won't be able do anything useful with it.

Comment: Your input looks like a fragmented JSON document. Would you mind showing the full input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data looks like a broken fragment of json, so you really should use `jq` to extract what you need from it **before** doing whatever it is you did to the original input that caused it to look like that.

However, to extract URLs beginning with `https://www` and not containing a double-quote character from what you have, you can use `grep`:

```
$ grep -o 'https://www[^"]*' input.txt 
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_china-seoul-startup-activity-6571925510337728512-acAw
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_reuters-top-news-on-twitter-activity-6571392661482233856-T3dO
https://www.mycompany.com/posts/aureliaflore_are-you-thinking-to-the-benefits-of-digitalization-activity-6570119712154451968-927T
```